# Mobile Friendly Bootstrap breadcrumb tabs

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble finding a place to start to make bootstrap tabs mobile friendly. I like the way they look on desktop but not the way they stack on top of each other on mobile.

Can anyone help me with css to shrinking the tabs down to look similar to the way they look on desktop?

Below you can find my html and css.

```
    <div class="centerTab">
        <div class="container breadcrumb">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-1" role="tab">Your Information</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-2" role="tab">Service Requirements</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-3" role="tab">Documents Needed</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-4" role="tab">Thank You!</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>      

      /* tab shape */
      .nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus, .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover {
        border:0;
        background-color:#fff;
        }
        .nav-pills > li > a {
            /* padding:10px 70px; */
        }
         .nav-pills > li.active {
         border-bottom:3px solid #005DA8!important;
         }

       .breadcrumb {
               background: #ddd;
               background-color: #e9ecef!important;
               display: inline-block!important;
               padding: 1px;
               padding-right: 15px; 
       }

       .breadcrumb li {
           display: inline-block;
           background: white;
           padding: 0;
           position: relative;
           min-width:50px;
           text-decoration: none;
           -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
           clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
           margin-right: -13px;
       }

       .breadcrumb li#last {
           -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
           clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
       }

       .breadcrumb li:hover {
           color: white;
           background: #fff;
       }

       /* first link should not have anything cliped on the left side */
       .breadcrumb li:first-child {
           -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
           clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
       }

       .label{
           height: 100%;
           width: 100%;
       }
```

Comment: You want to be careful about making things on mobile look like things on desktop. There is a reason someone made it NOT look like that, and it is usually because the UX is terrible on mobile. I agree that stacking isn't the best looking thing, but it's still functional, versus trying to read super tiny writing. Perhaps try something like BestBuy.com has? Where you can still go back to the last 'breadcrumb' but it only shows the one you're on? https://medium.com/madison-ave-collective/are-breadcrumbs-still-fresh-for-ux-6e72b0f96e9b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it :
give `width: 100vw;` to `.col-sm-3,.col-md-3,.col-lg-3` of bootstrap classes and override them after `link` tag of bootstrap

add to `style` tag in `head` section:

```
    .col-sm-3,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-lg-3 {
        position: relative;
        width: 100vw;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px
    }
```

and divide the html's nav items by  `.col-sm-3,.col-md-3,.col-lg-3` and putting them in a bootstrap `row`

HTML:

```
<div class="centerTab">
        <div class="container breadcrumb">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                <div class="row">
                    <li class="nav-item col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-1" role="tab">Your Information</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-2" role="tab">Service
                            Requirements</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-3" role="tab">Documents Needed</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-4" role="tab">Thank
                            You!</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

check:
https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/hLekd05v/

resize to see effect.
Thanks!!!!!!!!